# Getting selected row ID without metadata in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

```js
let dataSet = [{"_id": {"$oid": "6040bfdc1659e2002d990005"},"name": "page2VIM"}];
$('#policyTable').DataTable({
        rowId: '_id.$oid',
        data:dataSet,
        select: {
            style: 'multi'
        },
        columns:[{
            title: "Name",
            name: "name",
            data: 'name',
        }],
});
$("#delete").click((event) => {
   var listtable = $("#policyTable").DataTable();
   var selected_rows = listtable.rows({selected: true}).ids();
   $("#button").hide();
   console.log(selected_rows);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
        <table id="policyTable" class="cell-border hover stripe" width="100%"></table>
        <hr>
        <button id="delete">Delete</button>
        <button id="button">EDit Button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

When I click delete button after selecting table row I get the table rowId in console but I only need rowId not all the metadata that comes with it.Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.makeArray()` as in `$.makeArray(selected_rows)` then you will not get all the metadata

**Demo**

```js
let dataSet = [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6040bfdc1659e2002d990005"
  },
  "name": "page2VIM"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "222"
  },
  "name": "222"
}];
$('#policyTable').DataTable({
  rowId: '_id.$oid',
  data: dataSet,
  select: {
    style: 'multi'
  },
  columns: [{
    title: "Name",
    name: "name",
    data: 'name',
  }],
});
$("#delete").click((event) => {
  var listtable = $("#policyTable").DataTable();
  var selected_rows = listtable.rows({
    selected: true
  }).ids();
  $("#button").hide();
  console.log($.makeArray(selected_rows));
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <table id="policyTable" class="cell-border hover stripe" width="100%"></table>
  <hr>
  <button id="delete">Delete</button>
  <button id="button">EDit Button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice.Thanks A lot.A pretty simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

DataTables has a helper function [`toArray()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/toArray()):

```
console.log(selected_rows.toArray());
```

The statement `listtable.rows({selected: true}).ids();` returns a DataTables object containing the relevant results, with all that extra DataTables data you are not interested in (as you have seen).

The `toArray()` function converts this to a Javascript array.

In your example this produces the following console output:

```
Array [ "6040bfdc1659e2002d990005" ]
```